# Sending mail with CodeIgniter using SMTP protocol not working

Tags: codeigniter, ssl, smtp, gmail, email-spam

I have a problem in sending mails using CI. I used the "sendmail" protocol to send mail but it is being filtered as spam. I used the SMTP protocol to solve the problem, but it's not getting sent.

My code is as follows:

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => '*******@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => '********',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$message = "test mail";
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('dsiddharth2@gmail.com', 'St. Maries');
$this->email->to("dsiddharth2@gmail.com");
$this->email->subject('Contact - St. Marians Belguam');
$this->email->message($message);
if($this->email->send())
{
    echo "mail sent successfully";
}
else
{
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

When I send the email using "smtp" protocol in CI, I get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection timed out)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1673
```

and other list of errors...

I asked the server admin to enable the "openssl". It's been already taken care of and is enabled.

If you want to try it out, please visit [this link](http://www.stmariansbgm.com/marians/contactUs) and check for yourself.

Comment: Try using sendmail instead of smtp see how that works.

Comment: Yeah I tried using sendmail but its getting sent as "spam". I want it to appear in inbox. What are the conditions that tell gmail that a particular mail is a spam..? Thanks for answering Brad. Any other option that i can try..?

Comment: I am not sure, sendmail works perfectly for me but I am using my websites email. I could never get stmp to work no matter what I tried. I think Nettuts did a tut on this once. Check this out http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-3/   I thin k they used Gmail

Comment: Hi @Brad i did try their mail code and it worked on my other project(on some other server). But in this its not working, Is there any option in cPanel that i need to set or something..??? Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont think there is, Im not sure what you can do at this point. All I can say is triple check your settings to make sure nothing is wrong. I did get a Message successfully sent when I tried it

Comment: Hi..Yeah I had to show the demo to my manager so i implemented the sendmail protocol for now..But when i use smtp it is not working..I Have asked the problem to the server admin he may give me a solution. Thanks for replying. If i find any solution i will post back here..

Comment: Hi..I informed the server admin in which my site is hosted. And now if i use simple "mail" protocol of codeIgniter it is sending to the inbox of the user..:-) thanks for helping Brad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not working, check your php.ini file. Change this line

*;extension=php_openssl.dll*

to

*extension=php_openssl.dll*

It means remove the comment from the line in php.ini file.